# How to escape a double quote in BigQuery queries?

Tags: sql, string, google-bigquery, where-clause, sql-like

I wanted to update the strings contain double quote character, so I searched using this BigQuery query

```
select phonenumber from database
where  phonenumber like '%\"%'
```

but got no result. Something like `'%\\\\"%'` didn't work too, but searched for `\t` character using `'%\\\\t%'` did work. I don't understand how to properly escape special characters in BigQuery. Please help

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to escape the double quote. Doesn't this work?

```
select phonenumber from database where phonenumber like '%"%'
```

This is [explained in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical#string_and_bytes_literals):

> Quoted strings enclosed by single (`'`) quotes can contain unescaped
> double (`"`) quotes, as well as the inverse.
>
> ```
> "abc"
> "it's"
> 'it\'s'
> 'Title: "Boy"'
> ```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work "This query returned no results"

Comment: @camelot: then it means that the double quote is never there in your column... I added a quote from the documentation to my answer for your reference.